# Superlative Degree

Tags: articles

Sentence: *"I found this book **the** most interesting".*

According to my textbook, "*the*" is incorrect here and it should be only: *"I found this book most interesting".*

This sounds very strange to me, as with superlative degree we always use "the".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most interesting* is another way of saying *very interesting.*

*The most interesting* implies comparison with other similar things, for instance ...*of the books I have read this year*, or ...*of the movies I have ever seen*.

Comment: Does this rule only works for "interesting"? Next time when I attempt any question like this in spotting errors:- ......  ____ [superlative degree]. How can I know that *"the"* is required here or not like maybe some rule of thumb etc.?

Comment: When comparing one thing with some/all others, it's always _the most [adjective] (one)_ or _the largest, smallest_ etc. This has nothing to do with the fact that  _most_ can also mean _very_ .

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence stands alone without any context then you are correct, the *the* is not needed. If, however, there is a section which has been omitted then *the* would be correct. For example

> Of the whole library about quantum mechanics I found this book the most interesting.

Comment: Then what about this one: *"This is the most fascinating movie I've ever watched"* I'm not specifying any context (sci-fi/horror/action thriller etc.) but still using "*the*"

Comment: And we often use many superlative degree sentences in which we do not specify any context, but still use *"the"*